# Android Studio, gmaps and transparent top statusbar (MD)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-listview, material-design

I try make google maps with listview app in material design. But part controls from google maps are under statusbar. I try add to layout top margin/padding, but then status bar is grey.
That same problem is with ListView, part first select from list is under statusbar.

How resove this problem?
[image: Part controls from GM are under statusbar]
[image: The first item from List is under statusbar]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set primarycolor and color accent in your main style theme?

Comment: <resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>

Answer (score 0):

Add this tag to your view

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Comment: Add this into layout or in android mainfest?

Comment: Ok, I take this to 'ListView' and GM 'Fragment' - on 'ListView' working but on GM not. I'm looking in internet idea for this problem.